# Multi-Factor Authentcation when login to Windows 10 with Azure AD Account

Tags: azure, windows-10, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Is it possible to use Multi-Factor Authentication when login to Windows 10 with Azure AD Account?

I have a Windows10 PC which joined Azure AD during the first boot after OS installation(OOBE).
I wish to use 2-Factor Authentication everytime I login to Windows10, but I could not find a way to achieve it.

I know that Azure AD and Intune can be configured to enforce 2FA when "joining" Azure AD, but it does not enforce it at a normal login.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/multi-factor-authentication

I also enabled Multi Factor Authentication on Azure AD as described below, but it only applies to online services(Office365 etc.) and not Windows10 login.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates

I see that with Microsoft Account, 2FA can be enabled on the account setting page, but this setting is not available for Azure AD Account.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12408/microsoft-account-about-two-step-verification

None of the above helps to achieve what I wish to do.
I appreciate if anyone can tell me if it is ever possible or not with some reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately,there isn't a way to achieve this except using [Windows Hello for Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-identity-verification) for now.

You can upvote [this idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19319638-add-mfa-support-to-secure-the-windows-10-logon) in this feedback forum and Azure Team will review it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I wish it will become as easy as Microsoft Account 2FA. I will try Windows Hello for Business then.